# Python Flask: returns the same dictionary in every request

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying out Flask, I have this code:

```
responseDict = {}
responseDict["_hits"] = {}

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/server')
def showMain():
        query = request.args.get('q')
        responseDict["_hits"]["random string here"] = query
       
        return jsonify(responseDict)
```

Example:

- I make a simple GET `/server?q=earth`
- I make another GET `/server?q=moon`

I get the correct `_hits` dictionary with the query I provided, but when I make the `GET /server?q=moon` I also get the previous query, `earth`  How do I delete everything on `responseDict` when the request is done?

## Edit:

`responseDict` has to be a global variable because it's used for server logging.

Comment: Add `responseDict["_hits"] = {}` right before you send the response to reset the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`responseDict` is a global variable. This is why all the request will be added.
Try this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/server')
def showMain():
        query = request.args.get('q')
        responseDict = {}
        responseDict["_hits"] = {}
        responseDict["_hits"]["random string here"] = query

        return jsonify(responseDict)
```

Edit:
As you wanna keep `responseDict` as global variable. What about copying this and return it?

```
responseDict = {}
responseDict["_hits"] = {}

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/server')
def showMain():
        query = request.args.get('q')
        temp_responseDict = responseDict
        temp_responseDict["_hits"]["random string here"] = query

        return jsonify(temp_responseDict)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer buddy, But what if in case, I wanted to keep RD a global variable and destroy when completed (for the next request)?

Comment: thank you, keeping a temp dict is actually a good idea (y)